# realm-android-library not getting added to External Libraries

Tags: android, realm

Followed installation procedure mention in below link for 0.89.1 and 0.90.0 : https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#installation
Realm library getting added to External Library and able to work perfectly.

see below image 
[image]

Once I updated dependencies to latest version 1.2.0, same is not working and getting lots of error.

see below image
[image]

After adding 1.2.0, I am getting import errors e.g like below [image]

May I know what is the difference between 2 plugins, is there anything I missed to add here with latest version.

Comment: try clean and rebuild. There should be no changes in build between this two versions. Also, try to disable instant-run, sometimes it creates troubles.

Comment: When I tried  with 0.89.1 and 0.90.0, it was working well, only after 0.91.0, till 1.2.0 now working. Tried everything like you mentioned.
There is some difference might be part of new versions, which is not part of docs.

Comment: I was using deprecated methods  like clear, refresh and setModules.
changing this works :)